# MongoDB Push With Positional Operator Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document in a 'users' collection

```
{
    "_id" : "388179687996974",
    "matches" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "1495728740672094",
            "choice" : false,
            "dates" : [],
            "dateId" : null
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "385516561596016",
            "choice" : true,
            "dates" : [],
            "dateId" : "2014-11-26_385516561596016_388179687996974"
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "253752728167114",
            "choice" : false,
            "dates" : [],
            "dateId" : null
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "365296866955687",
            "choice" : null,
            "dates" : [ 
                "2014-11-26"
            ],
            "dateId" : null
        }
    ],
    "playDates" : [ 
        "2014-11-26"
    ]       
}
```

I have the following query

```
db.users.find({
  "_id":{"$ne":"385516561596016"},
  "playDates":{"$in":["2014-11-26"]},
  "matches":{"$elemMatch":{
        "userId":"385516561596016",
        "dates":{"$nin":["2014-11-26"]}}}})
```

It returns the above document.

I'm trying to update the document using the positional operator as follows:

```
db.users.update({
    "_id":{"$ne":"385516561596016"}, 
    "playDates":{"$in":["2014-11-26"]},
    "matches":{"$elemMatch":{"userId":"385516561596016",
          "dates":{"$nin":["2014-11-26"]}}}}, 
    {"$push":{"matches.$.dates":"2014-11-26"}})
```

Instead of putting 2014-11-26 into the match for userId 385516561596016, it puts it into matches[0].

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smells like a mongodb bug. I've tried a couple different variants.

```
db.items.update({
"_id":{"$ne":"385516561596016"},     
    //without the playDates $in clause
"matches":{"$elemMatch":{"userId":"253752728167114"} } } , 
{"$push":{"matches.$.dates":"test"} } )
```

This works as expected, putting "test" into the 3rd item.

This isn't a bug with the $push operator, as $set messes up too:

```
db.items.update({
"_id":{"$ne":"385516561596016"},     
"playDates":{"$in":["2014-11-26"]},
"matches":{"$elemMatch":{"userId":"253752728167114"} } } , 
{"$set":{"matches.$.other":"bob"} } ) 
//fails


db.items.update({
"_id":{"$ne":"385516561596016"},     
"matches":{"$elemMatch":{"userId":"253752728167114"} } } , 
{"$set":{"matches.$.other":"joe"} } )
//success
```

I think you should report it on the JIRA. https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa (If you're lucky they may fix it in a year. So far they've fixed 1/8 issues of mine.)

In the meantime, perhaps you can change your applogic such that the $in query on playDates isn't needed?

Comment: The joys of working with a toy database. Is there any potential workaround you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're querying two arrays in one query: `playDates` and `matches`.

MongoDB puts your data into `matches[0]` because your query matches `playDates[0]` with `{"$in":["2014-11-26"]}`, so MongoDB binds `$` to its index 0.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix it without removing `"playDates":{"$in":["2014-11-26"]}` part.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to match values from two different arrays-`matches` and `playDates`-  in a single query document. This is currently not supported in MongoDB.

As per the [dos](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation):

> The query document should only contain a single condition on the array
>   field being projected. Multiple conditions may override each other
>   internally and lead to undefined behavior.
>
> Under these requirements, the following query is incorrect:

```
 db.collection.find( { <array>: <value>, <someOtherArray>: <value2> },
                    { "<array>.$": 1 } )
```

Since the usage of `$` to update the matching sub document in one of the arrays, results in `undefined` behavior, the workaround would be to fire two queries,one to find the document, the other to update it once the values are modified in the app code.